# Strings[][] getting the value of an int

Tags: java

I'm working on a project the has quest's, All the quest data is saved in the player files. My method of saving the quest data in the player file isn't much of a method but a simple string of ints.

What I've done in User.java:

```
private final int[][] questData = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}};
```

The above code is saving the level of progress on all 5 quest's.

In my QuestHandling.java i've written the code:

```
    public static void checkQuestStates(User user) {
        if (user.questProgress[1][1] == 0) {
        System.out.println("Quest One Status = 0");
        }
    }
```

This was a test to see if I could get the value of the first int in the string (User.java).
Which leads to my question, How do I get the value of each int in the string & process it so I can do something like:

```
if (user.questProgress[1] == 0) {
        user.getPackets().sendConfig(29, 0); //(makes that quest (Quest #1) icon red a.k.a not started) 
}else if (user.questProgress[1] >= 1 && user.questProgress[1] != 10) {
        user.getPackets().sendConfig(29, 1); //(makes that quest (Quest #1) icon yellow a.k.a started
} else if (user.questProgress[1] == 10) {
        user.getPackets().sendConfig(29, 2); //(makes that quest (Quest #1) icon green a.k.a finished
}
```

---

Things I've changed & my errors:

what I changed:
in Player.java (User.java)

```
public int[] questProgress = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

and I've also tried:

```
public int questProgress[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

in questHandler.java I've put:

```
public static void checkQuestStates(Player player) {
        if (player.questProgress[1] == 1) {
        System.out.println("Quest One Status = 0");
        }
    }
```

& my command to test it is

```
case "statustest":
            StartQuestManager.checkQuestStates(player);
            return true;
```

When I type the command (just this command) I get the following error:

```
ERROR! THREAD NAME: New I/O  worker #1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.feather.game.player.quests.StartQuestManager.checkQuestStates(StartQuestManager.java:115)
    at com.feather.game.player.content.Commands.processAdminCommand(Commands.java:1239)
    at com.feather.game.player.content.Commands.processCommand(Commands.java:79)
    at com.feather.net.decoders.WorldPacketsDecoder.processPackets(WorldPacketsDecoder.java:1662)
    at com.feather.net.decoders.WorldPacketsDecoder.decode(WorldPacketsDecoder.java:279)
    at com.feather.net.ServerChannelHandler.messageReceived(ServerChannelHandler.java:98)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:95)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:91)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:247)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: questData probably shouldn't be final.

Comment: There isn't any `1,1` location, in the first place! Take a look at how you initialize the array.

Comment: @codeNinja yeah, I thought the same, another member on a different site was trying to help & told me to make it final & just gave me errors.

Comment: Where is the String[][]?

Comment: if your array for questProgress is the same array as questData you should be using position [0][0]

Comment: I updated the main post, I've added what I changed & tried & the error I'm getting.

Comment: NULL POINTER EXCEPTION. Means you haven't initialized something... Have you actually created an object of "User"?

Comment: When you type `StartQuestManager.checkQuestStates(player);` you get the error. `player` is an instance of `Player` I assume and you are passing it to the command. But how did you initialize `player`? Do you have somewhere in you code, before the command, the initialization of `player`, aka something like `Player player = new Player();`? And, even though you changed implementation, `int[][] questData = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}};` is not a `String` of `int` but a bidimensional array of `int` (or matrix if you like it more)

Comment: Also, last note, I don't see why you array should not be `final`. Writing `final int[] questProgress = {0,0,0,0,0}` means you are initializing an array with five elements, each element having value `0`. `final` means that, later on, you cannot reassign the array (you cannot write `questProgress = ...` a second time), but you can change values inside the array (you can, for instance, write `questProgress[0] = 1;`, which is, given your snippets, what I guess you do somewhere. Actually, I think you really what `questProgress` to be `final`, thus not re-assignable

Comment: @codeNinja: OP wants to change values inside `questData`, probably he does not want to re-assing it. So, `questData` should be `final`. In [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) you can read about `final` keyword. The sentence interesting for this case is: `Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value. If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: okay you've dropped the 2d array. lets do this again

```
private int[] questData = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

lets make this method a little more useful, and generic. Lets return a string. (it doesn't seem like you know how to use returns right now, as you've used void for all your methods)

```
public String checkQuestStates(User user, int questLine) {
    String sQuestData = "Quest 1 Status: "+Integer.toString(user.questProgress[questLine]);
    System.out.println(sQuestData);
    return sQuestData
    }
```

Comment: Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int. & how would I collect the int so that later I can have a param "int questId" & do the bit of code that sends config 29 above?

Comment: whoops forgot. Integer.toString(i); (where i is the int variable)

Answer (score 1):

As people have already said, you probably don't want `questData` to be final since you will be changing it later.

Additionally, remember that arrays are zero-indexed, so

```
public static void checkQuestStates(User user) {
    if (user.questProgress[1][1] == 0) {
        System.out.println("Quest One Status = 0");
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
public static void checkQuestStates(User user) {
    if (user.questProgress[0][0] == 0) {
        System.out.println("Quest One Status = 0");
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why you have an array of arrays, when the second dimension array only has a length of 1....would a regular array of ints work better for you?  That way, you can simply do:

```
if (user.questData[0] == 0) {
    user.getPackets().sendConfig(29, 0); //(makes that quest (Quest #1) icon red a.k.a not started) 
} else if (user.questData[0] >= 1 && user.questData[0] != 10) {
    user.getPackets().sendConfig(29, 1); //(makes that quest (Quest #1) icon yellow a.k.a started
} else if (user.questData[0] == 10) {
    user.getPackets().sendConfig(29, 2); //(makes that quest (Quest #1) icon green a.k.a finished
}
```

If I'm reading your question wrong, can you please clarify (as I don't see any `String[][]` question)?

Comment: It is assumed, as he expects to save the state of the game.  If he is initializing it that way, it must change at some point later, otherwise there is no purpose of the functionality as it will always be at 0.

Comment: Did you read my entire post?  The goal is to help him eliminate errors....why would I not help him past the question he asked? Especially when the question he asked wasn't thorough enough to be answered.  I'm just trying to help

Comment: @Vallentin, I will have to change the value of the ints (questProgress) Chris I'll look into it & try that. My real goal of this is to just save the progress of each quest that I can later read & see the progress of each quest setting the visual progress on the interface for each player(done by configs).

Comment: Read the comment I wrote on the question itself, it states the actual error.

Comment: @Ryan, see my comment to your question regarding the `final` keyword. You can change values inside the array, declaring it `final`. You can read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4 if you like to know more about `final`